# Mostrar icono cargando pagina justo antes de pasar o al principio de la siguiente pagina

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo un icono de 'cargando pagina' hecha en css que muestro con el código HTML:

```
<div id="loadingID" class="lds-dual-ring" runat="server"></div>
```

Necesito hacerlo visible antes de ir a la siguiente pagina con:

```
<a href="siguientepagina.aspx">
```

o justo al principio de la carga de 'siguientepagina.aspx'

En la pagina siguientepagina.aspx al principio de la carga se consulta a una base de datos que tarda unos segundos en extraerlos. Esta carga de datos esta en el 'Page_Load' y antes de la llamada a la base de datos pongo el icono de 'cargando pagina' visible. El problema es que no llega a salir el icono mostrando la espera porque la pagina en el Page_Load entiendo que aun no es visible.

Codigo en Page_Load:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   loadingID.Visible = true;
   Dataset ds = new DataSet();
   // La consulta a la base de datos tarda unos segundos
   ConsultaBaseDatos(ref ds, tabla, "");
   loadingID.Visible = false;
   // Mas código
   …
   //
}
```

Comment: Indica por favor, el código del evento `Page_Load` donde pones el icono de 'cargando pagina'.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta ya agregue el código que va a Page_Load

Comment: No vas a ver el efecto porque WebForms de .net no actualiza cambios directamente en el DOM de forma asíncrona, siempre hace un post y actualiza toda la página. Tienes que buscar la forma de hacer la petición asíncrona. Que de verdad no recuerdo muy bien pero usa AJAX.

Comment: @OscarDavidDiazFortaleché el problema es que si uso Ajax me obliga a usar en un metodo estatico en el servidor y entonces no me deja hacer referencia al elemento loadingID.visible dentro de ese metodo porque ese elemento no es estatico